# Recursive S3 calls in a package

Tags: r, recursion, r-package, r-s3

## What I want to accomplish

I have an R package with some internal R functions (called f and g in the example below) that are used in a recursive manner. In the minimal example the functions just return the length of their argument, but in the real code they trigger more complex calculations.

What I want to do is the following:

1. If the user passes an object to the function g, R should lookup if we have a S3 method we can call on this object.
2. If the object is a list, the function g should be applied to each object within the list. If we did not yet reached the maximum recursion depth go to 1. If we reached the maximum recursion level stop.

## Code that shows the problem

**It is important that the follwing code is put into a package. The error I get is only reproducible if the code is part of a package.**

`utils.R`

```
g <- function(x, depth = 0) {
  stopifnot(depth <= 1)
  UseMethod("g")
}

g.numeric <- function(x, depth = 0) {
  length(x)
}

g.integer <- function(x, depth = 0) {
  length(x)
}

g.double <- function(x, depth = 0) {
  length(x)
}

g.list <- function(x, depth = 0) {
  sum(sapply(x, g, depth = depth + 1))
}
```

`core.R`

```
#' @export
core_fun <- function(x) {
  g(x)
}
```

## What I expect

### Error

The result should be 6;

```
x <- c(1.0, 1.3, 1.5)
core_fun(list(x,x))
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("g") : 
no applicable method for 'g' applied to an object of class "c('double','numeric')"
```

### Passes

The result should be 3.

```
x <- c(1.0, 1.3, 1.5)
core_fun(x)
```

### Remarks

When I call the example, that fails, after loading the function g into the global namespace I get the expected result, 6.

So I think it is an namespace / S3 related problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with this Note in `?lapply`. If you run it with a wrapper as they suggest, the dispatch is done correctly.

```r
g.list <- function(x, depth = 0) {
  sum(sapply(x, function(x_i) g(x_i, depth = depth + 1)))
}
```

[image]